# Возведение в степень через цикл for

Tags: циклы, javascript

Исходный код:

```
var a = [5, 12];
var b = [];
a[99] = 7;
```

Записать в массив b квадраты значений 
массива a:
 с помощью цикла for
 с помощью цикла for/in

```
for (var x in a) { 
b = Math.pow(a[x], 2);
console.log(b);}
```

**Помогите реализовать через for**

Еще одно:

```
for (var i=0; a.length > i; i++){
if(!isNaN(a[i])) {
    console.log(Math.pow(a[i], 2))
    }
}
```

Comment: @msim, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

[подсказка Array.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: @msim, Вы дописали вопрос, а я ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так -

```
var a = [5, 12];
var b = [];
a[99] = 7;

var length = a.length;
var num;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    num = a[i];

    if(num != null){
        b.push(num * num);
    }
}

console.log(b); // [ 25, 144, 49 ]
```

**Дополнение:**
[[@msim](/users/20441/msim)](/users/20441/msim), Ваш добавленный вариант, наверное не очень правильный, так как незанятый элемент массива возвращает undefined, а не NaN. У меня в примере я проверяю на null, но это нормально, так как при нестрогой проверке undefined == null... Но не как не NaN...

Comment: я нашел инфу что undefined при приведении к числу возвращает NaN ,а null при приведении возвращает 0